# Finding set of extreme points and directions in an LP problem with constraints of constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, operations-research

Considering LP Problem z:

$z^*$ = min $x_{1} - x_{2} - 2x_{3}$  
s.t. $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 3$ 
$ 0 ≤ x_{1} ≤ 2$ 
$ 0 ≤ x_{2}$ 
$ 0 ≤ x_{3} ≤ 2$

and
$$ P=  \{ \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix}:  0 ≤ x_{1} ≤ 2, 0 ≤ x_{2}, 0 ≤ x_{3} ≤ 2\}
$$

If {$x^j$ : j = 1,...,k} be the set of extreme points of P and {$d^j$ : j = 1,...,l} be the set of extreme directions of P, how do find the value of k and l? I'm struggling because slack variables do not seem to work when $x_{1}$,$x_{3}$ are bounded both ways over range $(0,2)$. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: can I confirm that you are interested in the set $P$ and not the original feasible set?

Comment: What I initially wanted to do was 
1. find the k and l 
2. so that I can find the equivalent LP problem if the z* but expressed using { : j = 1,...,k} be the set of extreme points of P and { : j = 1,...,l}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is a cuboid with infinite length in the $x_2$ positive direction.

The base is a square, hence $k=4$ and $l=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, really helped me!!!